# how to detect the last bindview() called on a cursoradapter

Tags: android

I have a `CursorAdapter` that loads data into a list fragment. By definition, it's `bindView()` gets called a number of times whenever any changes happen on screen that changes the number or position of visible items.

**Requirement** : I want to send an async http request once after all the list items have been bound. For example, if there are 8 items visible on the screen, bindView() would be called approximately 8 times. And i want to start the async task at the end of the 8th call. Is there a way to check for the last call to bindview() so that i can start my async task then?

Comment: no, unless you extent the adapter and override bindView, or you could play with a fake ViewBinder

Comment: i have extended the adapter and overriden bindView. But i do not see any kind of field or method that indicates if the particular bindView() call is the last one, in response to a UI event.

Comment: take Cursor parameter of bindView and call getPosition and you are almost done

Comment: but that wouldn't give any idea of what position(out of 1 to 8) that cursor item occupies in the list view. So i still will not know when to start the async task.

Comment: getfirstvisibleposition() and
getlastvisibleposition()

Comment: you are absolutely right! thanks a ton! Not sure how to accept your comment as answer, so upvoting your comment.

Comment: I have realized the solution is actually not possible in bindView(). I have posted an answer with the explanantion

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find the last call to bindView() in response to a UI event. Better to start the async task in the `onScrollListener`.

The problem is that the relationship between the `cursor.getPosition()`, `getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition()`, `getListView().getLastVisiblePosition()`  and `getListView().getChildCount()` will always remain the same in `bindView()`, no matter if it is the 1st call or the 8th call or any call in between.

So, the below is always true -

in the case of a downwards scroll :

```
getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition() + getListView().getChildCount() = cursor.getPosition()
```

in the case of an upwards scroll :

```
getListView().getLastVisiblePosition() - getListView().getChildCount() = cursor.getPosition()
```

Comment: i dont get it, lets say first and last visible position define a "window", so eg we have a window 12..17 and a bindview gets called, a new window is 15..20 so the common part of those two windows is 15..17 so you know that only positions 18..20 will be bound, the same applies when window goes down e.g.10..15

Comment: yes you are right. but what I have explained in my answer is that there is no way to recognize the last call to bindView programmatically in response to a UI event like scroll. Taking your example, when a scroll happens, the 'window' changes with every call to bindView. so it would go from 12..17, then 13..18, then 14..19 and so on till 18..20. but there is no way to know programmatically that bindView will not be called after it reaches 18..20.